# What is input to the RF power amplfiier (gate of the MOSFET)?

Tags: rf, input, power-amplifier

I have read that the RF PA is a block just before the antenna. So, the input to the RF PA (voltage signal at the gate of trasistor in the PA) should be a modulated signal and thus the PA just does the job to amplify it. Is this correct? If yes, why do most of the books show a pure sine wave input and output while discussing RF PAs?

Also, in the class - E PA, the input (gate of the transistor) is a digital signal. Is that the data signal? If yes, in that case, does the PA itself do the job to modulate and output the amplified modulated wave?

I am confused as to what is the input to the RF PA.

Comment: Books show a pure sine wave input to the PA because it's easier to analyze than a modulated signal.  Much of PA performance can be measured with a swept sine wave rather than a modulated signal.  If the PA is linear, it should be fed by a modulated and filtered signal, but if it's class C a square wave would also work in theory.

Comment: Cool, I get it now! Also, In case of Class-E PA, the input is a squre wave, right? In that case, does it mean that there has to be some curcuitry in between (maybe switch drivers?) to convert input modulated signal to a square wave? And in this case, all the AM/AM and AM/PM analysis applies to the class-E PA considering input power from the modulated signal and not the square wave signal, right?

Comment: some RF chips use carefully tweaked sub-nanosecond pulses, combined, to craft the spectral response needed in adjacent-channel interference. RF can be very interesting, in the methods available (in modern times) to create "a sine wave".